# Django: using <select multiple> and POST

Tags: python, django, http

I'm using something like this in my template

```
<select multiple="multiple"  name="services" id="services" size="5">
    {% for service in services %}
        <option value="{{service.id}}">{{service}}</option>
    {% endfor %}
</select>
```

When I view the POST data in Firebug or the Django debug, I see it only sends one value.  Am I doing something wrong or misunderstanding a concept?

Comment: What's the value of services that's provided to the template?

Comment: Do you mean:

    services = Service.objects.all()
    return render_to_response('add.html', {'services': services})

??

(I cannot get these comments to format at all.)

Comment: @neoice: Hint: don't add details to your questions in the comments.  Edit your question to add facts.  The question always formats correctly.  AND the question should stand by itself without a thread of comments.

Comment: how did u get the value in jquery and pass it to django views??

Answer (score 196, accepted):

```
request.POST.getlist('services')
```

Comment: Jackpot! I think I _did_ need to change services to services[], but getlist r0xors for this. I thought I'd scoured the Django docs but apparently, I was wrong.

Comment: You don't need the []. That's a convention limited to PHP.

Comment: It might be worth mentioning that this also works for GET data. `request.GET.getlist('services')`

Comment: I needed to change services to services[] for Python as well.

Comment: Pretty late reply, you could use `FormData` and append your entities to it , and then `POST` using ajax with option `processData: false`, `contentType: false`. Find more [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6974684/how-to-send-formdata-objects-with-ajax-requests-in-jquery). This way, you won't have to put **[ ]** at the end of such arrays.

Comment: May you expand where this should be? If I replace it in the View, then when debuging I get the list but lost all of the extra fields.

Comment: Got it here. Thanks. Should have been mentioned in the django documentation :/

Answer (score 17):

Just FYI, I had to use:

```
    list = request.POST.getlist("items[]")
```

because omitting the [] caused a blank list to be returned instead of the correct values. I'm using jQuery to fetch the values of a multiple select element, and jQuery appears to be adding the []

Comment: I have to use [] wihtout any blank between

Comment: Yeah, I originally had the brackets with no space between them, then somebody came along and edited my response to include a space, which of course breaks the code because matching a literal "[]" is not the same as "[ ]"

Answer (score 2):

you can get the expected list just by using...

```
request.POST.getlist('fiel_name')
```

Answer (score 1):

Watch out! getlist method from QueryDict returns an empty list if the key doesn't exist. It does not throw an exception. http://bit.ly/MdgrUH

Answer (score 1):

request.POST.getlist('services')

Worked for me. or you can define select box name as a list