# Processing a django post request - one value getting assigned and other failes to assign dont know why

Tags: python, django, django-views

trying a simple post from html ..

when i receive the request in django i just do print post request. (counts is not getting reflected in my output dunno y..)

```
        print "counterUpdate"
    print request.method
    print request.path
    print request.POST.get
    print "Expects data of counts in next line console print but it is empty"
    countValues=request.POST['counts'] # counts is not getting reflected in my output dunno y..
    updateType=request.POST['key']
    print countValues
    print updateType
    print "dddd1"
    for data in request.POST:
        print data
    print "Iteration Over"
```

out for the following:

```
counterUpdate
POST
/testapp/counterUpdate
<bound method QueryDict.get of <QueryDict: {u'counts': [u'100', u'100', u'', u''], u'key': [u'increase']}>>
Expects data of counts in next line console print but it is empty

increase
dddd1
counts
key
Iteration Over
```

Comment: request.POST.getlist('counts') solved the isses

Answer (score 3):

You have to use getlist like:

```
request.POST.getlist('counts')
```

For more information: [Django: using <select multiple> and POST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/618557/django-using-select-multiple-and-post)