# Django - POST get options from select

Tags: python, django

I have a html form that looks like this.

```
{% url 'myapp:myapp_submit' as submit %}

<form name='main' method="POST" action={{submit}}> 
{% csrf_token %}
<select class='form-control' size=10 id="test" name='test' multiple>
<option>Test</option>
</select>
<input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

**and url.py**

```
from . import views

    app_name = 'myapp'
    urlpatterns = [
        url(r'^$', views.myapp, name='myapp'),
        url(r'results/$', views.myapp_submit, name='myapp_submit')
    ]
```

**and views.py**

```
def myapp_submit(request):
    print request.POST
```

The only thing I get back is

```
<QueryDict: {u'csrfmiddlewaretoken'...]}>
```

How do I get back the options held in the select tag? I would use the model/view form here but I'm doing some very crazy things with JS to constantly update the options available.

**UPDATE**

I have used:

```
request.POST.getlist('test')
```

But it will only return ['Test'] If I highlight it with my mouse. I simply want all the options under the select tag. ex.

```
<select class='form-control' size=10 id="test" name='test' multiple>
<option>Test1</option>
<option>Test2</option>
<option>Test3</option>
<option>Test4</option>
</select>
```

and

```
###Not sure if it's still getlist method
>>request.POST.getlist('test')
['Test','Test2','Test3','Test4']
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django: using <select multiple> and POST](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/618557/django-using-select-multiple-and-post)

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39217259/django-get-unused-all-options-in-a-select-tag where I cleared this up. Sorry for the double post

Answer (score 1):

Try to change your `views.py`:

```
def myapp_submit(request):
    request.POST.getlist('test[]')
```

Comment: This looks right - Let me try it on my actual select lists. Will get back to you

Comment: Hi, this is only returning the elements that are highlighted in the select. I just want all the options in a given select list.

Answer (score 0):

Because you say you're doing weird things with **Js**, you can first check the `POST` request from your browser and what parameters you send with it.

Comment: its not an answer. you can give a suggestion as a comment not an answer..

Answer (score 0):

A month ago I solved this problem, you need to use name in your option tag

Example:

```
<select name="status">
<option name="status">
```

and see result in your view.