# Django - Get unused/all options in a select tag

Tags: jquery, django

I'm using a POST form, but I'm not sure if that is the *best* way.

I have this:

```
<form name='main' method="POST" action={{submit}}> 
<select class='form-control' size=10 id="test" name='test' multiple>
<option>Test1</option>
<option>Test2</option>
<option>Test3</option>
<option>Test4</option>
</select>
<input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

If I use request.POST.getlist('test'), I get only the options that are highlighted. However, I would like all the options that are in the select tag.

ex.

```
def myapp_submit(request):
    #This method doesn't exist
    print request.POST.getalloptions
```

which would give me all options regardless if they are selected or not.

```
['Test','Test2','Test3','Test4']
```

#### why would I do this?

I'm using Jquery to use two select lists that you can select options from one list and put it in another. When the user submits I want to know which options remain in each select list.

#### Update -

Adam Brenecki says this method will never exist. What I can do is iterate through all my lists using JQuery and change all the options that are there to selected. However, can I have some help with this?

```
    //How can I change all options to selected
    $('#test').ChangeOptionToSelected;
```

Answer (score 1):

No such option exists because that data isn't sent to the server in the first place; only the selected values are.

Since you're using JavaScript on the client side already, you could programmatically fill a hidden form field, or send the values you want to the server some other way.

The other thing to think about is, you want to have two lists, a 'selected' and 'unselected' one *visually*, but *conceptually* what you're doing is picking multiple items from a list, which is what a single `<select multiple />` is for.

It might be best to have the underlying form field be a single `<select multiple />` that works normally, then build up the UI you want in JavaScript, hide the original form field from view, and update it. That way, visitors with JavaScript turned off are still going to get something that works, and it's probably going to be easier to make it accessible too.

Comment: Would it be possible to iterate through all my lists and just mark them all as selected when a user hits submit?

Comment: You could, but then you wouldn't know which one was selected beforehand.

Comment: yes I would, because when they are selected they move to a new list. When they are selected in that list, they move back. Perhaps that's a stupid way to use the select tags, but I'm new

Comment: I've updated the answer with some suggestions for a better way to use `<select>`. But yes, what you're suggesting would work.

Comment: Ok, I will just change input into a button onlcick=function that will change inside the accompanying javascript. Let me try that. Will get back