# select2 multi select box only takes in the last selected value into the array

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, django, jquery-select2

I recently tried using `select2` multi-select box in my `django` app, the `select2` box displayed properly and I can select multiple options like it should, but there is just a problem when the selected values taken into the array,

This is my code :

html page:

```
<head>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.10/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="{% static 'js/vendor/jquery-3.4.1.min.js' %}"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.10/js/select2.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('.recipientMultiSelect').select2({
                placeholder: "Choose Recipient Numbers / Groups",
                tags: true
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>

<body>
        <form action="{% url 'broadcast_single' %}" method="POST">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <div class="col-md-4">    
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="broadcast_name" class="col-form-label"> Broadcast Name: </label>
                    <input type="text" name="broadcast_name" class="form-control" required>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">    
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="recipients[]" class="col-form-label"> Recipient List: </label>
                    <select class="recipientMultiSelect form-control" name="recipients[]" multiple="multiple" required>
                        <option value="aaaaaa">aaaaaa</option>
                        <option value="bbbbbb">bbbbbb</option>
                        <option value="cccccc">cccccc</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
            </br>
            </br>
            </br>
            </br>
            <div class="col-xs-8 col-md-8">    
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="broadcast-content" class="col-form-label"> SMS Content: </label>
                    <textarea name="broadcast_content" rows="15" cols="85" maxlength="160" class="form-control"> </textarea>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-8 col-md-8">    
                <div class="form-group">
                    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-block mt-4" type="submit">Send Broadcast</button>    
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
</body>
```

Lets assume that all 3 options are selected and passed into the array `recipients[]`

views.py:

```
def broadcastSingle(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        bcName = request.POST['broadcast_name']
        bcRecArray = request.POST['recipients[]']
        bcContent = request.POST['broadcast_content']


        print('PRINT : ',len(bcRecArray))
        print(', '.join(bcRecArray))
```

bcRecArray should contain [ 'aaaaaa', 'bbbbbb', 'cccccc'] and the length should be 3

but instead, bcRecArray has [ 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c'] and length of 6

I think, the `select2` multi-select box only took the last selected value and turn it into an array of the letters in the selected value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the answer, from this thread :
[Django: using <select multiple> and POST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/618557/django-using-select-multiple-and-post)

I should be using request.POST.getlist('recipients') instead,
since the [] wouldn't work in django as its only a convention limited to PHP.

Thank you and I'll have this thread closed.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when using [bootstrapDualListbox](https://www.virtuosoft.eu/code/bootstrap-duallistbox/). The solution I came up with was to use a hidden text field, and then on submit, copy the values from the multi-select into the hidden text field:

```
        // "employees" is a jQuery handle to the multi-select.
        let data = employees.val();
        if (data.length === 0) {
            submitError('<p>{{ _('No employees selected') }}</p>', event);
        } else {
            //
            // We want ints, not strings.
            //
            data = data.map(x => parseInt(x));
            snapshot.val(JSON.stringify({"employees": data}));
        }
```

Back on the server, of course the JSON has to be unpacked from the hidden text field as needed.