# Get all value selected from bootstrap selectpicker multiselect

Tags: javascript, python, django, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-selectpicker

Using bootstrap selectpicker for selecting multiple options but when I fetch it using post method I get only the last value selected. However the selected values are displayed properly in the select box.

I am using Django framework and when I fetch value using **request.POST['selection']** it returns only the last value selected.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.13.1/css/bootstrap-select.css" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.13.1/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>



<select class="selectpicker" name="selection" multiple data-live-search="true">
  <option>Mustard</option>
  <option>Ketchup</option>
  <option>Relish</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Post values from a multiple select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11616659/post-values-from-a-multiple-select)

Comment: No @Robert I am using Django.

Comment: You may want to review https://stackoverflow.com/questions/618557/django-using-select-multiple-and-post then. Looks like you can resolve it by treating the named field as an array (ex. `name="foo[]"` or using some Django-specific functions.

Comment: This works, thank you @Robert.